# Dependency property not assigned when Loaded event fired

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, custom-controls, dependency-properties

`MainWindow` is using custom control:

```
<Window ... >
    <wpfCustomControlLibrary1:CustomControl Parameter="{Binding ParameterValue}" />
</Window>
```

View-model of `MainWindow` contains `ParameterValue` for binding:

```
internal class MainViewModel
{
    private string parameterValue;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.ParameterValue = "Test";
    }

    public string ParameterValue
    {
        get { return this.parameterValue; }
        set
        {
            this.parameterValue = value;
            $"Setter: {value != null}".TraceTime();
        }
    }
}
```

In custom control, I need to perform additional actions in `Loaded` event handler, and for this I need `Parameter` value:

```
public class CustomControl : Control
{
    static CustomControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl)));
    }

    public CustomControl()
    {
        this.Loaded += this.OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        // HERE I need to use Parameter value
        $"OnLoaded: {this.Parameter != null}".TraceTime();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Parameter", typeof(string), typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, PropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        $"DP: {dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue != null}".TraceTime();
    }
}
```

But at the moment when `Loaded` event triggers, `Parameter` value is still null. Here is trace output:

> [14:24:13.961] Setter: True
>   [14:24:14.173] OnLoaded: False
>   [14:24:14.235] DP: True

You can see that despite actual `ParameterValue` has already been set, `Parameter` dependency property evaluate it with delay and *after* `OnLoaded` fires.

**What custom control event can I use to be sure that all dependency properties evaluated?**

I can use `PropertyChangedCallback` for initialization, but it will became more complicated if I would have several parameters.

By the way, when value assigning directly `Parameter="Test"`, there is no delay, but I need binding.

---

```
public static void TraceTime(this object value)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff")}] {value}");
}
```

Comment: You could try the [DataContextChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontextchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event, but pay attention to the Remarks section on the MSDN page.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks, I'll try it, but according to _"The reevaluations can occur before the event, after the event, or in any mixture"_ sentence it seems like I still can't be sure all DP 100% evaluated. And I unfortunately begin to think that custom control should not rely on necessarily initial data providing, it should just have default logic and be able to change logic according to DPs changing.

Comment: "... custom control should not rely on necessarily initial data providing, it should just have default logic and be able to change logic according to DPs changing". Exactly.

Comment: @Clemens But what if this control contains complex data grid which should be completely customized by client? If I'll assign `DataContext` _before_ client provided his setting - all bindings (e.g. collection views) will be initialized by nulls. Will it be normal to assign `DataContext` _after_ DP with client setting will be changed?